# One Line Task: Check Range - CodeWars (using JavaScript's methods)

Tags: javascript, methods, shortest

> **Task**
>
> You're given an array of integers a and two integers x and y. Count the number of elements in the array such that `x ≤ a[i] ≤ y,
>   where i is the 0-based index of the element.
>
> **Code Limit**
>
> Less than 48 characters.
>
> **Example**
>
> For a = [2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 4, 11, 56, 49], x = 1 and y = 7,
>   the output should be 7.
>
> elements 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 4 should be counted.

I have tired `filter`, `reduce` and can't think any other possible way without making it longer than 48 characters.

Here's through using `filter`

```
checkRange=(a,x,y)=>a.filter(i=>i>=x&&i<=y).length
```

Using `reduce`

```
checkRange=(a,x,y)=>a.reduce((c,i)=>i>=x&&i<=y?++c:c,0);
```

Function call example

```
a =[95,92,27,55,55,20,40,8,7,45,87,14,44,35,64,84,95,85,69,47,53,49,95,54,97,7,67,31,76,97,7,24,82,61,10,34,34,85,66,96,65,2,84,4,68,74,46,50]
    x = 64
    y = 76

checkRange(a,x,y) // Expected: 8
```

I'm getting over 50+ characters so far....and I need to reduce them to 47.

Some Hints so far...

- Use another shorter method
- Count the index-values, rather than using `length`.
- Don't need `<= or >=`, only need `==`

I have gotten these from https://www.codewars.com/kata/one-line-task-check-range/discuss/javascript

Comment: Fun question! I'm at 48 chars using other tips from the thread, but I used > and <. Any enlightenment on the `==` tip if you happen to know it? I'm searching "bitwise between" and similar without result.

Comment: Here's where I'm at: `checkRange=(a,x,y)=>a.map(e=>e<x|e>y||i++,i=0)|i`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one passes all the test on codewars (thanks @ggorlen for the hint):

```js
a = [2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 4, 11, 56, 49];
x = 1;
y = 7;
checkRange=(a,x,y)=>a.map(v=>i+=x>v==v>y,i=0)|i;
console.log(checkRange(a,x,y));
```

It works by setting up a counter (`i`) using the `thisValue` parameter to `Array.map` which replaces all the values in `a` with the count of how many values pass the test `x>v==v>y` (by using `i+=x>v==v>y` - in an arithmetic context a boolean value is considered to be `1` (`true`) or `0` (`false`)). So for the sample array, we get `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7]` (although the only part we are actually interested in is the value of `i`). The test computes whether `x>v` and `v>y` are both the same, which can only be true when they are both false, which implies `x<=v` and `v<=y` which is our desired end condition. Finally the `|i` attempts to bitwise or an array with `i` which is equivalent to just `i` since an array in that context == `NaN`, and `NaN` bitwise OR'ed with a number returns that number.

Note that in the special case where `a` has one number in it, the output from `map` will be either `[0]` or `[1]` and this will successfully be converted to `0` or `1` for the purpose of the bitwise `OR`. In this case that number will be the same as `i` (since the output of `map` is an array of `i` values), so again the result of the bitwise `OR` will be `i` as desired. For example:

```js
a = [2];
x = 1;
y = 7;
checkRange=(a,x,y)=>a.map(v=>i+=x>v==v>y,i=0)|i;
console.log(checkRange(a,x,y));

a = [49];
console.log(checkRange(a,x,y));
```

Comment: Needs elaboration. What's `i+=` doing in this? It seems that it's concating true or false values? Then shouldn't we take "more than equal" operation into consideration? Why does having just `>` satisfy? And then how does the last `i` work?

Comment: @Abubakar101 added explanation. Hopefully it is clear.

Comment: I understood. Thanks for the explanation and I'd never assumed that concating the `true` Boolean would increment the number value.

Comment: @Abubakar101 it's not a concat, it's an addition (when `i` is initially assigned it is as a number (`i=0`)) and so the boolean becomes either 0 or 1 in that context.

Comment: can someone explain how a bitwise OR operator operates on the array?

Comment: @Kerron JS attempts to convert the array output by `map` to an integer for the purpose of the bitwise OR. It first does that by calling the `toString()` method, which in this case returns `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7"`. It then attempts to convert that to a number, which returns `NaN` as it cannot be converted because of the commas. NaN bitwise OR'ed with a number (in this case `7`) returns that number.

Comment: @Nick haha, brilliant explanation - thank you! Is there any resource you found this on that you can point me to? Nothing I found was this explanatory/in-depth.

Comment: @Kerron there's a bunch of stuff in the ECMAScript spec (starting from [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types) or [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-binary-bitwise-operators) that if you follow deep enough down the rabbit hole you will get to the same result.